# ng-repeat on array of arrays, orderBy subarray index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

Let's say I have this object:

```
var rows = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [11, 222, 3333, 4444]
];
```

Given that, and this template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy ????">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in row">{{ cell }}</td>
</tr>
```

...how can I order an `ng-repeat` by the second "column" of each row (the value at index `1` of the given `row` element)?

Am I correct that Angular does not support this case—without having to write a custom sort function? (I'm just prototyping, so using `ng-init` to define my scope variables instead of creating a controller.)

Answer (score 3):

Actually it does. You can create custom order by functions.

http://plnkr.co/edit/f6hCbHcLkrjyTODvDWjM?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:secondIndex">
    {{row}}
</div>

//In controller
$scope.secondIndex = function(arr){
    return arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just should to use `orderBy:'1'`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:'1'">
   <td ng-repeat="cell in row">{{ cell }}</td>
</tr>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/s3l0pAFt7abjJ65s3voF?p=preview)**

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner!

Comment: Great. But I don't understand why that orderBy value is string?