# Angularjs: How to sort array of arrays by nth value?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting

I have two groups of arrays.
First contains header fields =>

```
$scope.fields=[field0, field1, field2,...,field20];
```

Second has multiple arrays of data with respect to above field =>

```
$scope.data=[
    [A,B,C,...,someVal20],
    [Q,W,E,...,someVal20],
    [R,T,Y,...,someVal20],
    ...
    [B,N,M,...,someVal20]
];
```

Values of fields are shown in a drop down

```
<select ng-model="filteredOption" ng-options="option.label for option in fields"></select>
```

The same field values are used as table header.

```
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="f in fields">{{f.label}}</th>
</tr>
```

And the data as

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data">
    <td ng-repeat="i in d track by $index">{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Question is**
How do I sort (ascending) the data based on the 'nth' field (which user selects from drop down)? 
Its confusing because header and data are two distinct arrays, and data is not in key,value format.

**Plunkr** [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/leUGNcgIUO57NgcR087L?p=preview)

Comment: try providing a plnkr so others can help more easily

Comment: I think you should make a custom filter though

Comment: You may use some library method, e.g. underscore.js's sortBy

Answer (score 1):

> Column Header - ColumnName in you case it is field0

```
<th>
  <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'field0'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          field0
  </a>
</th>
```

On Column header click it sets the properties of sortType and sortReverse

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse"">
    <td ng-repeat="i in d track by $index">{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

useful link for sorting https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060199/2163837)** answer, I've found working solution.

I tracked the selected field's position ($scope.sorter set to that $index). And used it as `orderBy:sorter`

Still, keeping this question open for others to suggest more acceptable solution.